# PyQt5 multithreading: How to combine output of multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, pyqt5

I am trying to build a Python GUI using PyQt5 which incorporates multi-threading. Using various snippets of code (acquired mainly from Stack Overflow), I have come up with the code below which reads data from a csv file into a pandas dataframe and updates the GUI (triggered from a QTimer).

I would like to implement a 2nd thread which reads from a different csv file and a function which accepts both dataframes and does some computation on them before updating the GUI. I'm not sure how I can do this within the signals/slots framework of PyQt5. Any help is much appreciated!

```
import time
import traceback
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QTabWidget, QGridLayout, QApplication, QMainWindow, QStatusBar, QTableView)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QTimer, QAbstractTableModel, QThread, QVariant, QObject, QRect, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal)


class PandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    """
    Class to populate a table view with a pandas dataframe
    """
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._data = np.array(data.values)
        self._cols = data.columns
        self.r, self.c = np.shape(self._data)

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self.r

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self.c

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return self._data[index.row(), index.column()]
        return None

    def headerData(self, p_int, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            try:
                if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                    return self._cols[p_int]
                elif orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                    return p_int
            except(IndexError, ):
                return QVariant()
        else:
            return QVariant()


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    """
    Defines the signals available from a running worker thread.
    Supported signals are:
    finished: No data
    error: `tuple` (exctype, value, traceback.format_exc() )
    result: `object` data returned from processing, anything
    progress: `int` indicating % progress
    """
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    error = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal(object)
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)


class Worker(QObject):
    """
    Worker thread
    Inherits from QRunnable to handler worker thread setup, signals and wrap-up.
    :param callback: The function callback to run on this worker thread. Supplied args and
                     kwargs will be passed through to the runner.
    :type callback: function
    :param args: Arguments to pass to the callback function
    :param kwargs: Keywords to pass to the callback function

    """

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

        # Add the callback to our kwargs
        # kwargs['progress_callback'] = self.signals.progress

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        """
        Initialise the runner function with passed args, kwargs.
        """

        # Retrieve args/kwargs here; and fire processing using them
        try:
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(result)  # Return the result of the processing
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()  # Done


class MyTabWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tabs.resize(300, 200)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab 1")

        # Create tabs
        self.tab1.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)

        # Create table widgets
        self.table_widget1 = MyTableWidget(self)

        # Add tables to tabs
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.table_widget1)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


class MyTableWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)

        # Initialize tables
        self.table = QTableView()

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Create a central Widgets
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        # Create tab Widgets
        self.tab_widget = MyTabWidget(self)
        # Create a Layout for the central Widget
        self.central_layout = QGridLayout()
        # Set the Layout
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.central_layout)
        # Set the Widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)
        self.setGeometry(QRect(0, 100, 2000, 1500))
        self.setWindowTitle('CSV viewer')

        self.status_bar = QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(self.status_bar)

        self.proxy = None
        self.model = None
        self.show()

        # Setup worker thread
        self.worker_thread = QThread(self)
        self.worker = Worker(self.read_csv)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)

        # Connect worker signals to appropriate ports
        self.worker.signals.result.connect(self.process_csv)
        self.worker.signals.finished.connect(self.worker_thread.quit)
        self.worker.signals.finished.connect(self.print_refresh_time)

        # Setup timer to repetitively trigger start of worker thread e.g. every 5000ms
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.worker_thread.start)
        self.timer.start(5000)

    def process_csv(self, df):
        self.model = PandasModel(df)
        self.tab_widget.table_widget1.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.tab_widget.table_widget1.table.resizeColumnsToContents()

    def print_refresh_time(self):
        self.status_bar.showMessage('Last updated: ' + time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))

    @staticmethod
    def read_csv():
        df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Brian\\Desktop\\E0.csv")
        return df


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried just storing the results in some sort of data structure of you choice, as they come in (aka like your `process_csv`) and then also in that method checking to see if there are the correct number and combining if they are?

Comment: Yes I could certainly do that in this particular example @three_pineapples. I am interested, however, in how it might be implemented using multiple threads as this would be useful for more complicated projects in the future

Comment: My suggestion was for multiple threads (launch 2 or 3 threads and post results back as you do now and combine there). If that's not what you're after, I guess I'm not a 100% certain what you're asking. To me, multiple threads is easy if you construct a star topology of threads and use signals/slots to feed results back to a master thread (in my suggestion I chose the main thread because it can access the GUI, but it could really be any thread). This is only a small modification on what you've already done.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I would like to do but I am unsure of the implementation! For example, I can create a 2nd instance of the worker class (e.g. to read from a different csv) and a 2nd thread which is connected to timer.timeout without any issues. I would then like to create a 3rd thread which processes the data and feeds the results back to the GUI thread for display. Could you provide a snippet of code @three_pineapples that would lead me in the correct direction?